# Can the return value of this function be determined with static analysis?

Tags: assembly

I have an assignment and I tried solving it. However I can't seem to solve it, despite double checking everything and investing multiple hours.

My task is to reverse engineer the following functions to high-level C-code and determine the return value of `f(1,2,3)`.

**Given Task:**
[image: Task image]

**This is my approach:**

[image: My approach image]

**The problem:**

`f(1,2,3)` can not be determined, because line 6 in `function f` results in a jump to `loc_56C`, where `g(2,3)` is called. In line 14 `push dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]` is used, however only 2 parameter are supplied for `function g` at line 16 (8 Byte), meaning we do not know what lies on that memory location (12 Byte above base pointer). As a result, the return value can not be determined.

Is it true, that `f(1,2,3)` can not be determined?

Comment: `call` puts something on the stack too...

Comment: maybe think like what will ebp+8 be when f is called  like f(1,2,3)  and on what condition g() would be called ? or may be cheat for the sake of learning put this in an assembly file assemble and singlestep :)

Answer (score 3):

The control flow of the above program goes in following order `main -> f -> g -> f -> main`

`main` calls `f` with 1,2,3.

stack----
3
2
1
ret
ebp

Notice the push instructions and calling convention. `function f` checks whether `1 == 0` (ebp - 8). The answer is no. So, it calls `function g`. This is the major hint for you. I am sure you will be able to figure rest of it :-)